# Ansible doesn't finish some tasks

Tags: ansible

Friends,

the task bellow worked just fine when I was testing my playbook but it sometimes doesn't work in the real scenario:

```
- name: FETCHING FILE
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: wget http://dev2.brtloja.com.br/{{ brt_project }}/{{ brt_project }}.tar.gz
    chdir: /home/{{ gblix_usr }}
```

Ansible just don't finish the task although the file is already "downloaded" without problems. I realized, this doesn't happen when the file is smaller. Sometimes it happens as well with the following task:

```
- name: EXTRACTING FILES
  ansible.builtin.unarchive:
    src: /home/{{ gblix_usr }}/{{ brt_project }}.tar.gz
    dest: /home/{{ gblix_usr }}
    remote_src: yes
```

The file is completely extracted but Ansible just don't go the the next task.
Any idea how I could solve this kind of problem? This is the version I'm using:

```
python version = 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

As suggested, I ran `ps -eaf|grep wget` after realizing Ansible was stuck and it didn't return anything except:

```
softpla+ 31185 26080  0 11:32 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto wget
```

When using `-vvv`, the last log was:

```
<190.124.46.142> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o


ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no
 -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o 
PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="softplacemoveisb"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 
ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/8705f444d4 -tt 190.124.46.142 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'
/usr/bin/python
     /home/softplacemoveisb/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1623248317.4244783-
    218-140283574863523/AnsiballZ_command.py
    && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Comment: what do you see(when stuck) when `-vvv` is used?  also, when you say `wget` is stuck, do you see it in the output of `ps -eaf|grep wget` in remote node ?

Comment: When stuck, ps -eaf | grep wget doen'st return anything. I updated the question with the last logs of ansible.

Comment: try setting this before the execution and retry. let me know if it helps. `export ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-C -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o
ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s'`

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using [`get_url:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html)?

Comment: @mdaniel, not at all. I just didn't know the module until I saw the warning here. I will rewrite this part of my playbook. The problem happens as well while extracting the file so, I am first focussing on solving the problem before rewrinting the playbook. Thanks for the hint, will use get_url for sure.

Comment: most likely this is case of ssh timing out ..guessing

Comment: @P...., I did what you said. Lets see if it helps! Thanks anyway. I will keep you up to date.

Comment: @P...., it didn't work! I still facing the same problem!

Comment: what happens when you press "enter" key on the stuck window/terminal ? did it cause playbook to end or remain stuck ?

Comment: @P...., actually it seems to be working now. I will check tomorrow again and will l let you know.

Comment: @P...., it wasnt working. It keeps working only when the files are smaller.

Comment: sorry about it, you may use `get_url` or check out `ssh` config parameters of your remote node and controller node. when you said `ps` returned nothing, it proves that task is actually completed.

Comment: Thanks, @P.... I am rewriting the two mentined tasks here, will test it and let you guys know.

Answer (score 0):

To have a better error handling, troubleshooting possibilities, etc. the following approach by using the [module `get_url`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html) and as already mentioned in the comments might be helpful

```yaml
- name: Download or copy the package to the remote host
  environment: # dependent
    http_proxy: localhost:3128
    https_proxy: localhost:3128
  get_url:
    url: "https://{{ DOWNLOAD_URL }}/{{ VERSION }}/{{ PACKAGE }}_{{ VERSION }}_linux_amd64.zip"
    dest: "/opt/packages/{{ PACKAGE }}.zip"
    remote_src: yes
    use_proxy: yes
  tags: package,download

- name: Extract the package on the remote host
  unarchive:
    src: "/opt/packages/{{ PACKAGE }}.zip"
    dest: "/usr/local/bin/"
  tags: package,extract
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I will try this and come back here to post the news. Thanks a lot.